# How to hide a variable value when set -x is on

Tags: shell-script, mysql

I need to use set -x in my script to show the executed commands in my log

but there is a variable which is a password, so this password is showed in plan text

Is there a way to hide only a variable?

ie:

script:

```
pas=test123

set -x
mysql -uroot -p$pas
```

the output:

```
[root@server1]# ./teste.sh
++ mysql -uroot -ptest123
```

I want to remove `test123` from the output.

Comment: You can create a `~/.my.cnf` file to add username/password. Then, the shell will not print password.

Comment: Just don't use `mysql -p` that's insecure (as [the manual points out](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/connection-options.html#option_general_password)) and  bad practice.

Comment: One technique is to have `set +x` before the sensitive line(s) of code, and `set -x` again after.  Or avoid using the password in command arguments (as previous comments have said).

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. See [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `~/.my.cnf`:

```
[client]
user=DB_user
password="xxx"
```

Now, you can logon without using the `-u` and `-p` flags from within your script.

Note that it's not just the `set -x` output from your script that's a problem, but on most systems, the command line arguments of all running processes are visible in `ps` to any user, making passing passwords in them totally insecure. [This is also mentioned in the MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/connection-options.html#option_general_password) under the `--password` option:

> Specifying a password on the command line should be considered insecure. To avoid giving the password on the command line, use an option file. See [Section 8.1.2.1, “End-User Guidelines for Password Security”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/password-security-user.html).